# Where can find examples and tutorials for Perl's Net::Pcap module?

Tags: perl, network-programming

Could someone provide a good documentation / tutorial/ PDFs/ reference to book link about [`Net::Pcap`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::Pcap) in addtion to the [module documentation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::Pcap) and 
[this Perl and Net::Pcap article on PerlMonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=170648)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Chapter 2 materials](http://glasnost.itcarlow.ie/~pnb/chapters.html) for [Programming the Network with Perl](http://glasnost.itcarlow.ie/~pnb/). See also [an example included in the distribution](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/SAPER/Net-Pcap-0.16/eg/pcapdump).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a callback for every TCP/UDP/etc. packet matching a filter, you might find [Net::Pcap::Easy](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::Pcap::Easy) more convenient. You can `man tcpdump` for documentation on libpcap filter strings.